# Number of cycle partition of a set with repeating elements

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, permutations, set-partition, bell-numbers

We have a set $S$ with $E$ elements of which only $N$ are unique. We of course know how many repetitions of each of the $N$ elements are present: element $s_i$ is repeating $t_i$ times.

I would like to count the number of ways we can divide the $E$ elements in $N$ blocks of size $k_1, k_2, \cdots , k_N$ when the elements within the block are indistinguishable.

If the $E$ elements are all unique, we can answer directly using the Bell Polynomials.

Do you think is it possible to extend the above result ?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand if we have the multiset $\{2\bullet3, 3\bullet4\}$ meaning $2$ copies of $3$ and $3$ copies of $4$, and $N=3,$ then $2\bullet3,2\bullet4,1\bullet4$ is an acceptable partition, correct?  Does order matter?  Is the previous partition the same as  $2\bullet3,1\bullet4,2\bullet4?$

Comment: In your example $k_1=2,k_2=2,k_3=1$ and $S={3,3,4,4,4}$ the possible partitions are 5:
$(3,3)(4,4)(4)$ ; $(3,4)(3,4)(4)$ ; $(3,4)(4,4)(3)$ ; $(4,4)(3,4)(3)$ ; $(4,4)(3,3)(4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that  we have a simplified version of  the computation from
the                           following                           [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856255/).   Using  the
notation that was presented there we obtain the closed form

$$\left[\prod_{k=1}^l A_k^{\tau_{k}}\right]
\prod_{k=1}^m
Z\left(S_k; \sum_{k'=1}^l A_{k'}\right)^{\sigma_k}.$$

In terms  of combinatorial classes we  have made use of  the unlabeled
class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=\sigma_k}
\left(\textsc{MSET}_{=k}
\left(\sum_{k'=1}^l \mathcal{A}_{k'}\right)\right).$$

Note  that the  cycle  index will  create  the intermediate  multisets
during evaluation.